# using javascript in c# not working

Tags: c#, javascript, windows-phone-7

I am having trouble using a javascript function in my wp7 application. I am essentially attempting to create a Find on Page button like seen in the default IE browser on Windows Phone. So far I have referenced a javascript function from http://www.liveside.net/2011/10/21/tip-how-to-get-forward-and-find-on-page-back-in-ie9-mobile-on-windows-phone-7-5/ Find on Page option which will be accessed via a click event. my implementation is below which shows the Find on Page search bar as shown in the above link but nothing else happens, only the searchbar is shown and cannot be used. Any ideas on how to properly use this javascript function through my click event? Thanks in advance!

Javascript

```
javascript:(
function()
{
    function G()
    {
        var pf=doc.getElementById('pf');
        var qt=doc.getElementById('qt');

        if(null==pf)
        {
            pf=doc.createElement('div');
            pf.id='pf';
            var s=pf.style;
            s.position='absolute';
            s.zIndex='99';
            s.top=(scT||scBT)+'px';
            s.left=(scL||scBL)+'px';
            s.width='100%';
            s.backgroundColor='#FFFF00';
            pf.appendChild(doc.createTextNode('Search: '));
            qt=doc.createElement('input');
            qt.id='qt';
            qt.type='text';
            pf.appendChild(qt);
            var sb=doc.createElement('input');
            sb.type='button';
            sb.value='Find';
            sb.onclick=function()
            {
                P(qt.value)
            };
            pf.appendChild(sb);
            doc.body.appendChild(pf);
        }
        else
        {
            pf.style.display='inline';
            count=0;
        }
    }
function P(s)
    {
        document.getElementById('pf').style.display='none';
        if(s==='')
            return;
        var n=srchNode(document.body,s.toUpperCase(),s.length);
        alert("Found "+count+" occurrence"+(count==1?"":"s")+" of '"+s+"'.");
        pf.parentNode.removeChild(pf);
        return n;
    }
function srchNode(node,te,len)
    {
        var pos,skip,spannode,middlebit,endbit,middleclone;
        skip=0;
        if(node.nodeType==3)
        {
            pos=node.data.toUpperCase().indexOf(te);
            if(pos>=0)
            {
                spannode=document.createElement("SPAN");
                spannode.style.backgroundColor="red";
                middlebit=node.splitText(pos);
                endbit=middlebit.splitText(len);
                middleclone=middlebit.cloneNode(true);
                spannode.appendChild(middleclone);
                middlebit.parentNode.replaceChild(spannode,middlebit);
                ++count;
                skip=1;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if(node.nodeType==1&&node.childNodes&&node.tagName.toUpperCase()!="SCRIPT"&&node.tagName.toUpperCase!="STYLE")
        {
            for(var child=0;child<node.childNodes.length;++child)
            {
                child=child+srchNode(node.childNodes[child],te,len);
            }
        }
    }
    return skip;
}
var count=0,scL=0,scT=0,scBL=0,scBT=0;
var w=window,doc=document;
if(typeof doc.body!='undefined'&&typeof doc.body.scrollLeft!='undefined')
{
    scBL=doc.body.scrollLeft;
    scBT=doc.body.scrollTop;
}
if(typeof doc.documentElement!='undefined'&&typeof doc.documentElement.scrollLeft!='undefined')
{
    scL=doc.documentElement.scrollLeft;
    scT=doc.documentElement.scrollTop;
}
G();
})()
```

Click Event

```
public void FindOnPage()
    {
        var resource = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("Resources/FindOnPage.txt", UriKind.Relative));
        string text;
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(resource.Stream);

        while((text = sr.ReadToEnd()) != null)
        {
            TheWebBrowser.InvokeScript("eval", text);
        }        
    }
```

Note, the javascript function is placed in the text file FindOnPage.txt.

Comment: @Robert Harvey I have edited my comment to show my code. Currently the javascript function is being accessed by the click event but only the find on page search bar is showing, but I cannot use it as demonstrated in my original post's link. Any ideas of how to fix this so the find on page javascript function works correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The javascript function works fine. Change the FindOnPage method to the following

```
public void FindOnPage()
    {
        var resource = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("Resources/FindOnPage.txt", UriKind.Relative));
        string text;
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(resource.Stream);

        //while((text = sr.ReadToEnd()) != null)
        if ((text = sr.ReadToEnd()) != null)
        {
            TheWebBrowser.InvokeScript("eval", text);
        }
    }
```